# Beauty font, can someone help me to find this font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

can someone help me, whats font the letter "P"
2 days i spend my time to find this font, but nothing :( pls help me, thanks.
*sorry my english is too bad
[image: hte letter "P" font]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeface is Saraband Initials by Paul James Lloyd, the founder of [Greater Albion Typefounders](https://greater-albion.com/).